# difference in workflow design in sharepoint 2010 and sharepoint foundation 2010

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I am working on creating workflow to achieve the task to be approved by multiple level of approvers. I am having SharePoint Foundation 2010.

I have observed the less options/facility provided by Foundation to design workflow.

Can anyone share the details of what Foundation doesn't have for designing the workflow. Or confirm that all features of SharePoint 2010 to design the workflow is there.

Any kind of assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Foundation 2010 and SharePoint Server 2010 has different workflows. SharePoint Foundation only has the 3 state workflow template where you can some how use that to accomplish what you need. I created several approval workflows in SharePoint Foundation it is just not as easy and straightforward as the one in SharePoint Server.

Comment: Thanks Joseph for your quick reply and information. I would appreciate if you could share some details/tips to design custom workflows in Foundation.

Comment: For your approval workflow to work correctly.. Use the collect data from user action. Then create a form with two fields. approval status 'make it a choice field' then approval comments field 'make it multiple lines' then on your next step do a lookup on the task list using the variable that the action created to determine if the approval was valid or not.

Comment: Hi Joseph..As per your suggestion, we have created workflow with collect data from user action. But this is creating a new custom content every time and hence the action assigned to next user is received as new task(with ID different then the actual task to be assigned) and also the blank request entry is displayed for all users and approver too.                                                          I know, I am still missing something. Please assist me in this mater. Please let me know if I am not clear and you need more details of the issue.

Comment: Please modify the forms on the association task list to your preference. It will create a different task ID for each level of approvals. You will need to maintain reference internally on the workflow. I have a 6 level approval workflow working now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. we have managed it using workflow variables. I also need to develop same workflow for other allocations, at that time I will try this and will let you know if any thing will be needed. Thanks again for kind support.